# Excel 2016 crashes when typing space or line break in VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba

The title mostly describes the issue. I open a new blank workbook in Excel 2016, open the VBA editor, and I can type just fine until I try to type a space (or create a line break), at which point the program hangs and I get the "Excel has stopped working" message.

Oddly enough I can put spaces or line breaks in just fine so long as I haven't typed any other character, and tabs are fine to use whenever.

I've tried repairing MS Office but that didn't solve the issue.

EDIT: This also happens with an open or close parenthesis "(" or ")".

Comment: try turn off syntax checking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/turn-syntax-checking-on-or-off

Comment: @Tomasz thank you, it was the auto variable declaration that was causing it.